# Using Unity's new input system, how do I apply a jump height based on how long the jump button is pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, controls

I'm working with the new input system, and I have a simple code right now for jumping:

```
 void OnJump(InputValue button)
    {
        isGrounded = groundCheck.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground"));

        if (button.isPressed && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.velocity += new Vector2 (0f, jumpForce);
        }
    }
```

This works, but it's very rigid, being stuck to jumping the same height every time you press the button.

What could I do to have the player jump a height based on how long the button was pressed?

Here's a look at whole player controller for some context:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpForce = 15f;
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] Collider2D groundCheck;

    Vector2 moveInput;
    bool isMoving;
    bool isGrounded;

    
    void Update()
    {
        Run();
        Flip();
    }

    void OnMove(InputValue value)
    {
        moveInput = value.Get<Vector2>();
    }

    void OnJump(InputValue button)
    {
        isGrounded = groundCheck.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground"));

        if (button.isPressed && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.velocity += new Vector2 (0f, jumpForce);
        }
    }

    void Run()
    {
        Vector2 runVelocity = new Vector2(moveInput.x * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        rb.velocity = runVelocity;
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        isMoving = Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) > Mathf.Epsilon;

        if (isMoving)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(rb.velocity.x), 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner, so anything I tried may have simply not been implemented correctly.

I had a read through the unity manual on rigidbody physics, and tried instead of using a new Vector2 to the velocity, using AddForce. I'm not sure I applied it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It took me all day, but I finally found a working solution.

```
public void OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    bool jumpButtonPressed = context.performed;
    bool jumpButtonReleased = context.canceled;
    
    if (jumpButtonPressed && isGrounded)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    if (jumpButtonReleased && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (rb.velocity.x, 0f);
    }
}
```